# Why does initWithCoder has other self-object?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, initialization

I am a beginner with Xcode and Objective-C and stuck with a quite simple thing for over two days now. I hope you can help me.

My Project is deployed for OS X 10.6, it uses Garbage Collection and I am using Xcode 4.0.1.

I made a multi document application starting with the template provided by Xcode. I just have one class as subclass of `NSDocument`.

For opening documents I use `initWithCoder:`. The decoding within this method works fine - I get the values that were saved.
But these values are "lost" when I would like to use them in an other method (of the same class).

I assume that I make some mistakes with using the right comibation of init:  `initWithCoder:`, `initWithContentsOfURL:` etc.
The self-object does always have a different adress in the `initWithCoder:` method then in the other methods.
I tried plenty of combinations of the above methods and even tried to call different methods in the super class (`NSDocument`) within `initWithCoder:`.

This is my header file:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface OptimiererZwoMultiDoc : NSDocument <NSCoding> {
    __strong struct bildanalyse { 
        float winkelo;
        ...
        float skalfak;    // Der Skalierungsfaktor, den dieses Bild erfahren muss damit es so gross ist wie das kleinste - Wert ist also immer <= 0
    };

    __strong struct bildanalyse *analyse;
    __strong int16_t anzahlanalysewerte;
    ...

@private
    NSTextView *ausgabe;
    ...
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification;
- (void) prepareAnalyseDoc;
...

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTextView *ausgabe;
@property __strong struct bildanalyse *analyse;
@property __strong int16_t anzahlanalysewerte;
@end
```

When I try this implementation:

```
#import "OptimiererZwoMultiDoc.h"

@implementation OptimiererZwoMultiDoc

@synthesize ausgabe;
@synthesize analyse;
@synthesize anzahlanalysewerte;
...


- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    NSLog(@"init self=%@",self);
    if (self) {
        ...
    }
    return self;
}


- (NSString *)windowNibName
{
    NSLog(@"windowNibName self=%@",self);
    return @"OptimiererZwoMultiDoc";
}


- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)aController
{
    NSLog(@"windowControllerDidLoadNib self=%@",self);
    [super windowControllerDidLoadNib:aController];
}


- (BOOL) readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError{
     NSLog(@"readFromData self=%@",self);
     [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: data];
     if (outError) {
         *outError = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSOSStatusErrorDomain code:unimpErr userInfo:NULL];
     }
     return YES;
}


- (id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *) coder{
    struct bildanalyse tempAnalyse;

    NSLog(@"initWithCoder self=%@",self);
    anzahlanalysewerte = [coder decodeIntForKey:@"anzahlanalysewerte"];
    ....
    return self;
}
```

then I get this output:

> init self= OptimiererZwoMultiDoc: 0x2002955a0
>
> readFromData self= OptimiererZwoMultiDoc: 0x2002955a0
>
> initWithCoder self= OptimiererZwoMultiDoc: 0x20028f5e0
>
> windowNibName self= OptimiererZwoMultiDoc: 0x2002955a0
>
> windowControllerDidLoadNib self= OptimiererZwoMultiDoc: 0x2002955a0

As you can see, the object self is different in `initWithCoder:`. Why? What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

Your `-initWithCoder:` is missing a `self = [super initWithCoder:coder];`. I’m not sure why your `-init` and `-initWithCoder:` are both being called—an object that’s getting unarchived from a NIB should just be receiving the latter—but the above would be a good place to start.

Comment: Thank you for your Input. As far As I can See has the super Class (NSDocument) nö initWithCoder method. I Spread tried Fällung init in the super Class wirblig success.

Answer (score 0):

It's because (provided the document info in your Info.plist is set up correctly) Cocoa's document-handling machinery automatically instantiates your NSDocument subclass for you. So if you're using -initWithCoder: to manually create your own subclass instance, chances are that one is completely superfluous.  I'd suggest reading through Apple's [Document-Based Applications Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Documents/Documents.html) before going much further.

Comment: I alread Read this. In my Klimmzug I did it right. But well - my Klimmzug seems ti Be wring...

Comment: The problem is the [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: data]; in your -readFromData: override.  This is returning an entirely separate copy of your document, which you are then not assigning to anything (so it gets leaked).  You need to use -readFromData: to read data from the file into your current document, not create a whole new document.